# .NET MAUI: Switching the App's MainPage multiple times leads to exception

Tags: c#, android, navigation, maui

The root of a .NET MAUI application is the class `App : Application`.

This class has a property `Page? MainPage` that contains the current root page.

I try to use this property for navigation. I wrote a method `App.ShowPage(Page page)` that sets the property `MainPage` to the given page.

This works like a charm! I start my application and show a login page - works.

When the user clicks login on my login page I show the main view (a TabbedPage) - works.

When the user clicks on an item on that main view a details view gets shown - works.

Now when the user clicks cancel on that detail view, I try to navigate back to the main view. As always with my method `App.ShowPage(Page page)`. Now I get an exception:

> IllegalStateException; The specified child already has a parent. You
> must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

So the error message tries to tell me what to do. And I do find properties like `Element Parent` or `Element RealParent` on the `Page page` I try to open - but they are all `null`. So how do I remove the page from that parent? What is the `removeView()` method in the .NET MAUI world?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Always show code. **Add to question** the code for *"I try to navigate back to the main view."* You can't "navigate back" because you don't have a navigation stack. That's because you set MainPage each time, so there is no stack. Start with `MainPage = new NavigationPage();`, and see NavigationPage's doc to understand how to navigate to pages within it.